# PHP Mysql Query (INSERT) Issue

Tags: php, mysql, insert, insert-into

I am having an issue with a MySQL query as follows:

My script generates this as an example query:

```
INSERT INTO `contacts`(`name`, `phone`, `email`, `city`, `state`, `date`) VALUES ('Test2', '123-456-7890', 'test@test.com', 'mesa', 'az', '04-14-2013')
```

Which if I drop directly into PHPMyA, works fine. However, the PHP script I am trying to use to send the query from my website is not working and I can't get it figured out. Here it is:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts`(`name`, `phone`, `email`, `city`, `state`, `date`) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', '$city', '$state', '$date')";

mysql_query($sql);

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result)
{
    echo("<br>Data Input OK");
} 
else
{
   echo("<br>Data Input Failed");
}
```

Nothing makes it to the MySQL DB and no PHP errors are displayed, however, if I echo `$sql` I get the exact query I posted previously.

Comment: Did you print your query to see whether all the expected values are there? Also just a note you are executing your query two times, so once you get to fix it, it will be doing 2 inserts per run

Comment: you're running the query twice, your second attempt might be the one that's failing

Comment: why not just `print(mysql_error());`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the single line `mysql_query($sql);` on your code and you will be fine.. But you should better start practicing PHP MySQLi which stands for **PHP MySQL Improved**, such:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $password);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts`(`name`, `phone`, `email`, `city`, `state`, `date`) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', '$city', '$state', '$date')";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if($result) {
    echo("<br>Data Input OK");
} else {
    echo("<br>Data Input Failed");
}
```

Comment: problem cannot be twice usage of `mysql_query($sql)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Table_name (`id`, `name`) VALUES ("1", "php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running mysql_query twice. Reason of the error. Try running the following code.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts`(`name`, `phone`, `email`, `city`, `state`, `date`) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', '$city', '$state', '$date')";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if($result){
    echo("<br>Data Input OK");
} else{
    echo("<br>Data Input Failed");
}
```

Comment: Agree but it's not the main issue here

Comment: Query being run twice is not the error OP is asking about, they don't see data in there for even one run of the query

Comment: Try debugging the code by using `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` Check and see what causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `$sql` twice in your script wich is causing the error, please remove

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

And it will be ready to go

I would also suggest to stop using `mysql_query` please switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: Once cleaned up to only run the query once, and $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); is added I am greeted with the message "No database selected" which I find perplexing since I am staring at my mysql_select_db line... Not sure where the error is, but its time to backtrack my way through the connection string

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a valid connection (..mysql_connect())? Try using the full syntax like so..

```
$conn = mysql_connect(...);
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
```

Also try forcing a commit after you execute the statement -

```
$mysql_query("COMMIT", $conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mysql_query($sql,$con);` instead of `mysql_query($sql);`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
"INSERT INTO `contacts`(`name`, `phone`, `email`, `city`, `state`, `date`) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[state]', '$_POST[date]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $name=$_POST['name'];
   $age=$_POST['age'];
   $address=$_POST['address'];

   $ins="insert into table_name(`name`,`age`,`address`)values('".$name."','".$age."','".$address."')";
   mysql_query($ins);
   echo 'data inserted successfully';
}
```